# вывести сведения о том, когда СУБД была обновлена до текущей версии и какие версии СУБД были установлены на сервере в прошлом

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Есть задание такое, подскажите как достать такую информацию из словаря данных oracle. Полный текст такой:
Используя сведения из представлений словаря данных, вывести сведения о том, когда СУБД была обновлена до текущей версии и какие версии СУБД были установлены на сервере в прошлом(включая даты).

Answer (score 1):

Выполните запрос:

```
select * from DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY where ACTION='UPGRADE';
```

Описание таблицы приведено [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4057.htm#REFRN23549)